# Returning distinct or grouped records from a postgres DB using active record queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I'm stuck on an AREL call I'm trying to write for a Rails 4.1 application with a postgres database.

My app has activerecord classes for User and League (users table and a leagues table) and they're joined via a has_many relationship with a user_leagues table.

I'm trying to write an instance method on League that returns *users from this league ordered by the end_score column in the user_leagues table*. I could do it with Ruby, but it seems like it should be doable with pure AREL.

In pseudocode: select * from users ...inner join user_leagues... group_by user_id order_by end_score

My latest attempt:

```
  def ranked_users
    User.joins(:user_leagues).
    where("user_leagues.league_id = ?", self.id).
    group("user_leagues.user_id").order("user_leagues.end_score DESC")
  end
```

I've tried different variations with group and distinct, but all of them return some variation of this error:

```
PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "users.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one...I think it should work:

```
User.joins(:user_leagues).
  where("user_leagues.league_id = ?", self.id).
  order("user_leagues.end_score DESC")
```